# Get exceptions from Oracle procedure in Java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

Hello guys right now I'm working in this problem, I have an Oracle stored procedure, this one find the employees by the given Last Name. But when I found no rows I want to catch the No Data found exception in Java.
Here's the procedure

```
FUNCTION GETEMPLOYEE_LASTNAME(LASTNAME IN VARCHAR2) RETURN CUREMPLOYEE_LASTNAME
IS CUR_NAME CUREMPLOYEE_LASTNAME;
BEGIN
OPEN CUR_NAME FOR SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE LAST_NAME = LASTNAME;
RETURN (CUR_NAME);
EXCEPTION when NO_DATA_FOUND
then
NULL;
END GETEMPLOYEE_LASTNAME;
```

And this is how I made the call procedure in java.

```
public List<String> getEmployeeList(String lastName)
{
    List<String> listaEmp = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {           
        OracleCallableStatement oraCallStmt = null;
        OracleResultSet deptResultSet = null;

        oraCallStmt = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{? = call DEPTOSYEMPDISPO.GETEMPLOYEE_LASTNAME(?)}"
            );

        oraCallStmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        oraCallStmt.setString(2, lastName);
        oraCallStmt.execute();
        deptResultSet = (OracleResultSet) oraCallStmt.getCursor(1);//This is the cursor with the data.

        while(deptResultSet.next())
        {
            System.out.println(deptResultSet.getString("LAST_NAME"));
            String Resultado = deptResultSet.getInt("EMPLOYEE_ID") + "     " +deptResultSet.getString("LAST_NAME")+ "\t\t";
            listaEmp.add(Resultado);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return listaEmp;

}
```

It works nice, when I have data found and when there's no data no problem, but there's a way to call the exception from oracle, I mean if there's no data, Just jump to to the cath(Exception){/* NO DATA FOUND MESSAGE*/ } and show a message about this.

Comment: What does "cathExeptions()" mean?

Comment: by that I mean, just to to the cath(Exception){} block. That's confuse I will edit that part.

Comment: What happens if you simply don't handle `NO_DATA_FOUND` in the stored procedure? I imagine that would cause the database driver to raise a `SQLException` in on the client side in the Java code.

Comment: Nothing. It will return the empty cursor, no problems. Based on justin cave answers using the cursor will never have an error so no exception, the solution for this is count the number of rows in java and use an if in order to show the information dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `no_data_found` exception will be raised because it is not an error to execute a query that returns 0 rows.

If you want to consider that an error condition, the caller (in this case your Java code) would need to attempt to fetch from the cursor, find that no rows are returned, and then raise an exception (assuming that it really makes sense in that case to raise an exception rather than just using an `if`).  That would realistically involve adding an `int` to your Java code to count the number of rows fetched that is incremented in your loop and then an `if` statement after that looks to see whether your code fetched 0 rows.